# How can I run ES6 semicolumnless code in a windows 10 cmd window without babel?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, semicolon-inference

How can I run a short ES6 (Javascript) program without semicolons?

I have the following code in a `jstry.js` file

```
let v = 1
console.log(v)
```

I open a CMD window in windows 10, run it and get an error that a semicolon is expected. What can I change (without babel) so that this code is run OK?

Remark: I understand this is supposed to be supported in ES6, and that in actuality it was even supported before but...  now comes some explanation that I don't really understand: until ES6 came along and then something (that I don't understand either) happened.

My path is:

```
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VSCode\bin;   
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VSCode\bin;
```

So maybe running in the cmd window is invoking nodeJS? I'm running 8.11.1

Comment: Are you running this with Node? Babel is not necessary, but you need a consistent JS execution environment first.

Comment: I'm running it in CMD in windows 10 . I'll update the question with my path, which will probably tell me what is running the .js file. No?

Comment: Your code is perfectly valid. A problem might be that if you run this script by entering its filename only (not `node filename`), that it is run by `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`, which doesn't support ES6.

Comment: @FZs Could you make that an answer and I'll mark it. That was it/

Comment: I've posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is perfectly valid in ES6** (note: there's no thing called ECMA6, it's ECMAScript 6 or abbreviated as ES6).

A problem might be that if you run this script by entering its filename only (not `node`*`filename`*), that it is run by the [Windows Script Host](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) (`cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`), which is the default way of running `.js` files on Windows; however, it doesn't support ES6.

To solve this issue, you have multiple ways:

- Always run scripts by prepending its filename by the name of the program, in this case, `node`, or
- Change the default program associated with the file extension `.js` to Node.js ([here](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-file-associations-in-windows-2624477)'s how to do it)

Comment: I'd recommend changing the default program for `.js` files to an editor. Accidentally running scripts you might have lying around can cause quite some issues.